# how to display a picture from a folder php

Tags: php, html

I have a folder where uplaoded files are saved. This page is used to retrieve those saved files. A picture called "flower.jpeg" is in the folder, and I am trying to display the picture using an image tag, as shown below. I have two options, but none of them is working.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php

        $picture=flower.jpeg
        $playfile='/upload/$picture';

    ?>
        // <img href= '<?php $playfile ?>'  width="800" height="600">   
        // <img src= '<?php echo $playfile; ?>'  width="800" height="600">  <br>

    <script>
        document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Go Back To Chat</a>');
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What happens when you try? What errors are reported in the server logs? What does a directly listing of `/upload/` look like?

Comment: your code is right, the path (playfile) might be wrong.

Comment: the folder upload is in the same direcdtory as this html code

Answer (score 2):

flower.jpeg requires quotes and the $playfile assignment is not properly specified as, to my knowledge, strings within single quotes are not parsed for variables within PHP.

```
$picture='flower.jpeg';
$playfile='/upload/'.$picture;
```

Additionally correct use of the  tag is as follows

```
<img src="<?php echo $playfile; ?>"  width="800" height="600">
```

As the attributes need enclosing by double-quotes, you are just using PHP to echo out a variable containing a string.

Comment: Updated, but this really is VERY basic.  As to whether /upload/flower.jpeg is the correct path, that is something that only you can really tell.  We don't have access to your file system / configuration

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of what is wrong. You're using the following code to build your link:

```
$picture=flower.jpeg
$playfile='/upload/$picture';
```

First off, you need to quote the picture

```
$picture = 'flower.jpg';
//or
$picture = "flower.jpg";
```

The next problem is how you're building the `playfile`. You need to exit single quotes to use a variable or use double quotes:

```
$playfile = '/upload/'.$picture;
//or
$playfile = "/upload/$picture";
//or even
$playfile = "/upload/".$picture;
```

The single quotes will take the text as is where the double quotes will evaluate variables in them. I suggest continuing to read up on the basics of PHP and strings.

Comment: doesn't still work, please is the image source or the image href correct?

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo $playfile; ?>" width="800" height="600">` Should be the syntax. What HTML shows? (view source)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps that *may* help you in finding if the path to the image (or the 'href' as you call it) is correct. No direct solution is possible as we do not have access to your file system, as Simon pointed out.

- Check if the file extension of your picture is mentioned correctly. Check also that it is in the correct CAPS. For example, if you saved your picture using MS Paint, the extension will be *.PNG but your script may contain *.png; this *may* cause problems in some cases.
- .jpg and .jpeg are two different extensions sometimes (in the sense of the above point). You may want to take that into consideration.
- You may want to verify that the directory structure of the image is correct (i.e. verify that you are specifying the correct path to the file).

Hope this helped you in some way. The above steps are rough and vague. If they failed to help you, please comment, and someone will be able to help you.